# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61 on Apple Arm

Tags: macos, flutter, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio Canary `2020.3.1.22` and trying to run `Flutter` project on `Apple Silicon(ARM) Mac`. Unfortunately, it is giving me this error when I try to run `default` flutter counter app.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/khamidjonkhamidov/StudioProjects/dummy/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/khamidjonkhamidov/.gradle/caches/6.7/scripts/f0emg6u6oecmxqzgk5g9nn4ui).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61
```

`Gradle version: 6.7` but I tried 7+
JDK version `17`

I would really appreciate your help)

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73509483/4479395

Comment: If there is same error for major version 64, change gradle distrubution url in properties to version 8.1.1 it works!

Answer (score 166, accepted):

According to the official grade docs: Java 17 and later versions are not yet supported.

You can check compatibility [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html).

So I have installed `Java11` from [Azul](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-11-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk).

p.s. don't forget to change jdk version in Android studio which is available only on the Android project, to open it

`File-> open -> select the android folder inside your flutter project -> open in a new window`

Then you can change jdk version
`Preferences -> Build -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK`

Comment: I've got the same issue when trying to port my grade build with Java 8 to Java 17.

Comment: As of Gradle v7.3.0 Java 17 works fine

Comment: Downgrade is the last resort, it should NOT be encouraged...

Comment: I would like to thank you for this answer, one small comment, to change the project Gradle you have to open the Android project in the Android studio, not the Flutter project, because the Flutter project doesn't have the option, so simply from android studio, File-> open -> select the android folder inside your project.

Comment: @Chandler if you have an old flutter project, you don't have many options until you upgrade the flutter version itself and resolve the code issues

Comment: Yes, Chandler you are right.   I have many old android which worked with older version of flutter and gradle, and after compiling with an older version of version, everything worked.       The mention about Azul JDK is awesome, first time I see this.

Answer (score 46):

I faced this error when I updated my android studio

**Solution:**

you need to upgrade the `distributionUrl` field in your in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file according to the `java version`

‌Below is the `Java version` and Supported `Gradle version`

[image]

Comment: Source of this compatibility table (for future release): https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: In few cases the Kotlin version compatibility section in the above Gradle documentation helps:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#kotlin

Answer (score 33):

Got the same error while I upgraded my build.gradle to Java 17. And the fix is as simple as we think:

```
Gradle starts supporting Java17 only from 7.3 release
```

Here's the complete reference for Java vs Gradle compatibility:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Upgraded my gradle to 7.3 in gradle-wrapper.properties.

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

Some of you may experience now the **Gradle dependency cache corrupt error** after this like me. So better delete the gradle-wrapper.jar and reinstall it using the command:

```
./gradlew wrapper
```

Everything will work perfectly fine from here.

In case if you still face Gradle corrupt issue, please check whether you are using latest version of IDE especially Intellij.

Answer (score 25):

First, you can execute this command: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, to retrieve all installed jdsk:

```
[~]$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V

Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    17.0 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 17.0" /Users/ciccio/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0/Contents/Home
    14.0.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 14.0.1" /Users/ciccio/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1/Contents/Home
    11.0.12.1 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 11" /Users/ciccio/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.12/Contents/Home
    10.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 10.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_302 (x86_64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8" /Users/ciccio/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_302/Contents/Home
```

Now, imagine you want to remove the version **17**:

```
[~]$ java -version
openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17+0, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Go into the path of the version you want to remove (in this case "*/Users/ciccio/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0/Contents/Home*"), and delete entire folder:  "**/Users/ciccio/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0**".

Once removed, go back on terminal and use:

```
[~]$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 14.0.1 --exec javac -version
javac 14.0.1
```

to force the new version to use (14.0.1).

Next check if is correct:

```
[~]$ java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
[~]$
```

Your Gradle now is back to work.

Answer (score 25):

Happened with newly created Flutter app in 2023 January with Mac Mini M1. If you have another working Flutter apps do not downgrade or update Java version as it will cause problem with all other working ones. Find gradle-wrapper.properities file inside `gradle/wrapper` folder (directly inside Android folder) and check gradle version. You just need to use newer version of gradle. I replaced this one and used `flutter run` command from terminal and it worked:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

With this one:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
```

No need to do anything else. Version number may be different for you depending on when you are trying this and what Java version you have.

Note: Same fix also effective for another error message as well stating version 63:

```
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63
```

Answer (score 23):

There is no need to downgrade Java version. Just upgrade Gradle

1. Select the gradle version which supports your Java version [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)
2. Open your project and navigate to `your_project_name/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
3. Change `distributionUrl` Gradle version according to your Java version. You can see the list here: [gradle list](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Comment: While this information may be helpful, consider editing the formatting of your post (use the built in list format) and remove unnecessary comments like "Finally I got the Solution" and "it is very easy to solve as these tend to serve as spam and distract from the real information in your answer.

Comment: Good stuff, just updating it from 7.5 to 7.6 to work with java 19, did the trick!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank's very much for that. Unfortunamtely, android studio ran into another problem after solving this one :-(

Comment: This is the right and concise answer !

Answer (score 14):

Basically, I installed jdk using `brew install java` which was not compatible with my current gradle I guess. So

1. I uninstalled java first using: `brew uninstall java`
2. installed `JDK 8 or JDK 11` from [azul](https://www.azul.com/products/core/?utm_term=java%20development%20kit&utm_campaign=S%20-%20Platform%20Core%20(Zulu)%20-%20NB%20-%20EMEA&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=5970432568&hsa_cam=13383756860&hsa_grp=127174056631&hsa_ad=531015396886&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-299913935885&hsa_kw=java%20development%20kit&hsa_mt=p&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=CjwKCAjwpMOIBhBAEiwAy5M6YNbVMbKk__lr1kPgbfqe27IWgESCNxhILSIIIy2M9jMARprX2_aZsxoCv1QQAvD_BwE).
3. Installed gradle: gradle-6.9-all.zip

When done, everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I had this set

Typing `flutter --version` on terminal:

```
Flutter 3.7.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c07f788888 (10 weeks ago) • 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600
Engine • revision 0f359063c4
Tools • Dart 2.19.2 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

Typing `javac -version` on terminal to get you java version:

```
javac 19.0.2
```

So, by this [grade compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) I had to update my `project/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` **distributionUrl** to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
```

Comment: And if necessary, after this, close the IDE (in my case VS Code)  and reopen it. The error is gone. That worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I found a way to fix this error without messing with the locally installed Java version or Gradle. Here is what I did:

1. If you are developing a Flutter project and got this error, go to **File** -> **Close Project**.
2. Then re-open from the android folder (omit this if you received from a pure Android project).
3. Now, Gradle may detect the issue on its own, and it will take a while to check. After it is done, it may provide **upgrade steps** in an upgrade assistant window at the bottom of the window along with logcat, build, terminal etc… which you need to accept and tell it to execute. Once it finishes, the error is resolved, and you are good to go.
4. If it does not seem to do anything on its own, then please open the **Project Structure** tab. Now select the latest Gradle version available that does not contain *-rc* (you don't want these, most of the time they are not stable releases).
5. Now select the JDK version that Gradle uses by going to **Gradle** (sidebar on the right of the window) -> **Wrench Icon** -> **Gradle Settings**. Select a compatible JDK version according to the Gradle project's documentation, as found **[HERE](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)**. Current latest stable version of Gradle is 7.4 with maximum supported JDK version 17 (also latest I believe if you use something like [openJDK which I use](https://openjdk.java.net/)), but Android Studio version at 7.1 so be careful.

Tested on MacBook Air M1 running macOS Monterey 12.2.1.

Answer (score 5):

Check currently active java version:-

> javac -version

If it is greater than 11 downgrade it to 11 or 8. Check your available java jdk version installed:-

> /usr/libexec/java_home -V

If java 11 or 8 is not installed first install one of them using this link:- [Download jdk 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8)

then change the default java version in .bash_profile

**Edit .bash_profile**

> sudo nano ~/.bash_profile

Add 1.8 or 11 as default. (Add below line to bash_profile file)

> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)

**OR**

> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)

Now Press CTRL+X to exit the bash. Press 'Y' to save changes. And reload bash_profile

> source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 3):

## Windows Users

Open Android Studio and Click on Setting ICON far right. And Go to Project Structure Option and select the SDK's Version 11.0.15 and click apply than on the left side click on Module Option and select Module SDK's options and select Project SDK 11. and at the bottom at Project Settings CLICK on SDK and select on 11 SDK versions. It will give you the JDK path

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr`

Copy this path and Open the System Environment Variable Create a New `JAVA_HOME` path with the location
[image]

and click OK and save everything Now run your app in ANDROID STUDIO and ENJOY!

Answer (score 3):

## Error

```
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/khamidjonkhamidov/StudioProjects/dummy/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/khamidjonkhamidov/.gradle/caches/6.7/scripts/f0emg6u6oecmxqzgk5g9nn4ui).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64
```

## Steps To Solve :

1- open the gradle prodperties see the current project gradle example "gradle-7.4"

2- open compatibility see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

3- download java version, in ower example java 17
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

**System:** Mac M1, Android Studio Electric Eel (2022.1.1 Patch 1), JDK 19.02

I encountered this error when created a fresh project using `flutter create` and tried to run it in Android Studio.

Now I've got an interesting solution that worked for me:

1. Open the flutter project in Android Studio
2. Open **build.gradle**, the one under *android* folder
3. On the top right it shows "Open for Editing in Android Studio" (although it's already in Android Studio!). Click on that to open it for editing. I opened it in another window, but doesn't matter.
4. It starts to automatically download and update gradle to sync the build file. At one point, tt might also prompt you to upgrade gradle, which is good to do.
5. Done! Close the build.gradle and re-run the project. It should build and run fine.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix in 2023:

1. Command in the terminal:

   export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
2. Check classpath, current working one:

   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
3. Check gradle-wrapper.properities file:

   ```
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
   ```
4. If still not solved you need to change Gradle JDK from inside Android Studio like below.

[image]

After that you can run fluter app directly from terminal without any issue. Note: Android Studio default JDK (11.0.15) does not work and causes this issue. Azul Zulu 16.0.2 works and solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Context: Flutter, Mac M1, Java 19.0.2

Problem occured on following command:

```
flutter build apk
```

I just installed (reintalled) gradle via homebrew like this:

```
brew install gradle
```

I suppose it was related to my recent upgrade (Java was upgraded to OpenJDK Temurin 19.0.2).

I also noticed that flutter command was trying to use gradle 7.4 (the only one gradle version installed before). As previously mentioned by others, there has to be consistency between your Java version and gradle version according to [Gradle Official Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html).

Please, verify it with following commands:

```
java -version
gradle -version
```

I think this process / solution can be applicable in general. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solve by cleaning and upgrading the flutter project
use these command on your terminal

--> flutter clean
then run
--> flutter upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this bug relates to the incompatibility of the gradle version and the JDK version.

if you want to be sure. first check [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) for compatibility.

if this is your problem. find your version in [this](https://gradle.org/releases/), then rename your version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to clone a Flutter project from GitHub that was working perfectly until the last commit and push. After deleting it locally and cloning it again, I encountered an error when opening it in Android Studio.

**Solution:**

Open the Android module of the Flutter project in Android Studio.

Set the Gradle JDK to zulu-17 by going to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle. In my case, the Gradle Plugin Version was 7.2.01, which can be found in File > Project Structure > Project. Check the Gradle documentation to find the compatible JDK versions for your Gradle version.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Run java -version in the Flutter project's terminal window. In my case, it showed a different Java version than zulu-17.

Set the JDK path in the .zshrc file located at /Users/homepathname/.zshrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Users/homepathname/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-17.0.7/Contents/Home"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Open a new terminal window in the Flutter project and run `java -version` again. This should show the same Java version as the Gradle JDK.

The project should now run without any problems.

This solution worked for me as it synchronized the Java versions used by Gradle and the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I was seeing this b/c in Egypt, ISPs often block `jsdelivr` :(

Here's a related issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11939#issuecomment-1582406310

So I installed & ran Nord VPN, re-ran `pod install`, good to go

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your distribuiton url in app\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to the latest version with this link ,  distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{latest version}-all.zip.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I set the target for a new IntelliJ Kotlin project to be Java 17. My fix was to:

- set the target to 9 in `build.gradle.kt`
- close the project
- delete the `.gradle` and `.idea` directories from the project folder
- remove the project from the recent projects list
- open the gradle file from IntelliJ and get it to rebuild everything

Answer (score 0):

Open the Gradle settings and change the Gradle JVM to the same JDK version you are using.
(I am using 14.0.2)
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had that Issue creating Projects from IntelliJ.
It seems the issue was the Gradle JVM Version.

Here is a configuration that works:

System:
Mac with ARM, Mac OS 12.1, M1 Max

- java version 18.0.1-zulu
- kotlin version 1.7.0
- gradle version 7.5

I installed those version with sdkman https://sdkman.io/
and set the config manually on intellij (See attached Screenshot for Details)

[IntelliJ Gradle JVM config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEcER.png)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to open the android project in Android Studio. It detected the needed Gradle update and performed the update upon command.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for everyone, but for me, I went into Flutter project's file `android/gradle/gradle.properties`, and changed the `org.gradle.java.home` value so that it pointed to a folder containing JDK 11 instead of JDK 18. That way, it used a JDK version that was actually supported.

Answer (score 0):

Giving my two seconds here...
In my case, I could fix it by finding my gradle version in the file gradle.wrapper.properties and checking the compatibility with the JDK, so I needed to install the JDK 16, so in my build.gradle(:app) I put this line of code inside the android {} :

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
}
```

After this I build my android version again, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

On my side I fixed this issue by setting the default `Java Version` to `8` (download it if needed)

Mac:

1. Open Terminal.
2. `open ~/.bash_profile`
3. Add

```
# SWITCH TO JAVA VERSION 8
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

4. Save and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on VSCode+Mac using the [Gradle for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-gradle) extension.

My project uses Java 17 but Gradle was using JDK19, which I also had installed.
I removed the `jdk-19.jdk` folder from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and then ran the "Clean Java Language Server Workspace" task in VSCode.

After that, Gradle successfully built and I was even able to put the jdk-19 folder back and things continued to work.

Answer (score 0):

***Changing the Java Version in the Intellij resolved the issue***.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use the react native cli and my android gradle is 7.3.1. I open the android folder in the android folder in the android studio and it suggests my gradle once after degradation it works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by triggering the Gradle task in Android Studio's context menu using my mouse. Attempting to execute it through the command line resulted in the error mentioned in the title of this question.

Also I deleted .gradle folders from `/users/account/.gradle` and `project/.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the gradle version at Two places:

```
 1. android>gradle>wrapper - change the distribution url
 2. android> build.gradle  under dependencies change gradle version
```

Gradle veriosn should be compatible with install java. You can check from here.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue when ugprade the jdk version to 21. Upgrade the gradle version to 8.4 fixed this issue.