# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file mmajor version 63

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'E:\React\EasyWhere\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\7ph2xz2y917gbgrv3cc7uh5mv).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

> How to fix the  problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you edit your question to give us some context on what you were trying? Also, could this question maybe be relevant to your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597899/bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis-in-source-unit-buildscript-unsup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)