# I am facing the flutter installation error

Tags: flutter, installation

I have facing the issues " exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63 " in Flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GseRk.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597899/bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis-in-source-unit-buildscript-unsup Already posted and solve do try.