# I'm getting an error in my flutter code when I use BLoC. what should I do to get the code running. The error is shown as given below

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Dines\Desktop\New folder (9)\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Dines.gradle\caches\6.5.1\scripts\nj0dc4o4zfdtg2l3tavvbnpv).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

I tried to change my java version to 14 so that my gradle version matches but still I'm getting an error.

Comment: Hello, Kindly, try Java 17 instead of 14. And make sure your JAVA_HOME is set to Java 17.

Comment: My java version was 17 before and it showed the same error

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597899/bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis-in-source-unit-buildscript-unsup

Comment: What is the JAVA_HOME?