# games_services always returning null when calling signIn()

Tags: flutter, google-play-services, flutter-dependencies, google-play-games

I followed all the steps here: https://akdebuging.com/posts/integrate-gamekit-and-google-play-services/

Added to AndroidManifest:

```xml
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="MY_ID" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

In Google Play Console everything seems fine (the SDK is not marked as done, not sure if related):

[image]

When I call this it returns just `null`:

```
Future<void> signIn() async {
    final result = await GameAuth.signIn();
    print(result);
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue , could you solve it??

Comment: I did: https://github.com/Abedalkareem/games_services/issues/129#issuecomment-1847027074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resume everything:

- Add test users for both OAuth consent screen and Google Play Console --> Play Games Services --> Testers
- Get debug and release key from running `./gradlew signingReport`

If last command fails:

- Upgrade Android Studio and Flutter
- Check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597899/bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis-in-source-unit-buildscript-unsup/76159868#76159868) and update `gradle-wrapper.properties` if necessary

Real demo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drodriguez.time_tap

More info: https://github.com/Abedalkareem/games_services/issues/129