# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I'm trying to create an Android App with Cordova on Windows 10, with Java 11 and Gradle 8.5, I added environment variables and path, and when i run the build command, i have this error message:

```
C:\Users\Moi\applisCordova\appliBima> cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Moi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Moi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Moi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloCordova'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Moi\applisCordova\platforms\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Moi\.gradle\caches\7.6\scripts\9bna54a4rj2471vdp83mbbooi).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Moi\applisCordova\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\Moi\applisCordova\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug
```

I don't understand why it says that deprecated gradle features were used when the path for gradle is correct. I also don't know what "BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 65" means.
Can somebody help me out please ?
I tried to go back to a lower version of gradle (gradle 7), but it didn't change anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '\_BuildScript\_' Unsupported class file major version 61 on Apple Arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597899/bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis-in-source-unit-buildscript-unsup)