# Can't build Qt app apk to android 11 "Unsupported class file major version 65"

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, gradle

I have followed all the steps on this video: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-getting-started.html.

But on section "Building and deploying an example to an emulator" where it shows that kits should be automatically created and I had none. All my configurations are green

[image: Print showing that Android settings are OK. (SDK Version: 12.0, NDK Version: 25.1.8937393)]
[image: Print showing that OpenSSL Settings are OK.]

I have tried to set the JAVA_HOME variable but it didn't changed anything.

When trying to create a new project I see the following error, does it have a log so I can debug it better?
[image: Print with warning message "Android has not been configured. Create Android kits."]

So I tried creating a kit myself but it didn't work:
[image: Print with kit configurations]

Then after a restart Going into Edit>Preferences>Compilers and saw the error "Failed to detect the ABIs used by the Qt version. Check the settings in Devices > Android for errors." on all Android Clang compilers. Removing the folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtProject\QtCreator\cache\CachedStores` did the trick, restarting Qt now gave me the default kits all configured!

But when trying to build to android I get the following error:

```
Generating Android Package
  Input file: C:/Users/.../builds/build-ANDROID-qt-Android_Qt_6_5_3_64_bit-Debug/app/android-qt-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: C:/Users/.../builds/build-ANDROID-qt-Android_Qt_6_5_3_64_bit-Debug/app/android-build/
  Application binary: ...
  Android build platform: android-31
  Install to device: No
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Windows
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.macOS
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.iOS

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\...\builds\build-ANDROID-qt-Android_Qt_6_5_3_64_bit-Debug\app\android-build\build.gradle' (C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\8.0\scripts\et9...).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
09:00:30: The process "C:\Qt\6.5.3\mingw_64\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project ... (kit: Android Qt 6.5.3  64-bit)
When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

I found it odd that the bin being used is the mingw_64 instead of the android_x86_64 bin but as it is a androiddeployqt so I think it's right? What can be done to solve it?

EDIT: well someone flagged this as duplicate. It is duplicate kinda of [BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61 on Apple Arm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68597899/12172630) maybe but that does not highlight the Qt misdirected download. The duplicate stated here has nothing to do with the problem plz flag it right to [BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61 on Apple Arm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68597899/12172630) if anything :v. Reading the duplicate provided link will not help solving the issue, as "There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way." moderator should read https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

- "What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations of the question."
- "bear in mind that cultivating and supporting a moderate amount of natural duplication actively helps the community."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some godforsaken reason the version of Java that you need to install can't be the one on the page that Qt send you when following the video instructions and clicking on QtCreator little globe shortcut for downloading the JDK...

You need ojdk for Java 17 (it can be Eclipse Temurin but you need to click on the "Other platforms and versions" button and filter for the version 17 LTS). That's because Qt use Gradle 8 for bundling the APK, and it supports only up to Java 17. But maybe it's because I was trying to bundle for Android 11 if anyone smarter than me can confirm it would be nice.