Can't able to get signingReport in Flutter due to error
I am trying to get SHA keys using the command ./gradlew signingReport. But I am getting the following result.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\Users\Dell\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65


Your problem should be same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597899/bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis-in-source-unit-buildscript-unsup

What gradle version are you using? Looks like you need 8.5 or higher, since Java 21 only supported from 8.5
